# Accumulator in foldr

Tags: haskell

In the Haskell Wikibook, foldr is implemented as follows:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f acc []     = acc
foldr f acc (x:xs) = f x (foldr f acc xs)
```

It is stated that the initial value of the accumulator is set as an argument. But as I understand it, acc is the identity value for the operation (e.g. 0 for sum or 1 for product) and its value does not change during the execution of the function. Why then is it referred to here and in other texts as an accumulator, implying that it changes or accumulates a value step by step?

I can see that an accumulator is relevant in a left fold, such as foldl, but is the wikibook explanation incorrect, and only for symmetry, in which case it is wrong?

Comment: Accumulation in foldl happens from the left and accumulation in foldr happens from the right.

Comment: Yeah that is interesting.  It'd probably be more appropriate to call the second argument of `f` the accumulator. I usually write foldr-esque patterns with either `z` (connoting zero) or `nil` (connoting the constructor case it corresponds to).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the evaluation of a simple `foldr` expression based on the (correct) definition you provided:

```
  foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3,4]
= 1 + foldr (+) 0 [2,3,4]
= 1 + 2 + foldr (+) 0 [3,4]
= 1 + 2 + 3 + foldr (+) 0 [4]
= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + foldr (+) 0 []
= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 0
= 10
```

So you are right: `acc` doesn't really "accumulate" anything. It never takes on a value other than `0`.

Why is it called "acc" if it isn't an accumulator? Similarity to `foldl`? [Hysterical raisins](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html)? A [lie to children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children)? I'm not sure.

Edit: I'll also point out that the GHC implementation of `foldr` uses `z` (presumably for zero) rather than `acc`.

Comment: Well, its an accumulator that doesn't change :P

Comment: @alternative not funny

Answer (score 1):

`acc` doesn't really accumulate anything in the case of `foldr` as has been pointed out.

I'd add that without it, it's not clear what should happen when the input is an empty list.

It also changes the type signature of `f`, limiting the functions that can be used.

E.g:

```
foldr' :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
foldr' f [] = error "empty list???"
foldr' f (x:[]) = x
foldr' f (x:xs) = f x (foldr' f xs)
```

Comment: what you describe is `foldr1` and it indeed errors on empty lists.